# how can i pass a bean value as parameter from jsp to servlet using hyperlink?

Tags: jsp, servlets

welcome.jsp

```
         <display:column title="User Id" property="userId">
          <bean:write name="user_Id" property="userId"/>

         </display:column>
     <display:column title="First Name" property="firstName"></display:column>
          <display:column title="Last Name" property="lastName"></display:column>
           <display:column title="User Name" property="userName"></display:column>
            <display:column title="Password" property="password"></display:column>
             <display:column title="Mail Id" property="mailId"></display:column>
              <display:column title="Age" property="age"></display:column>
               <display:column title="Gender" property="gender"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Mobile Number" property="mobileNumber"></display:column>
                <display:column title="Qualification" property="qualification"></display:column>

                <display:column title="Update"><font size="+1" face="comic sans ms" colour="blue"><a href="login.do?method=modify&userId=${user_Id}"  style='text-decoration: none;'>Update</a></font></display:column>
                <display:column title="Delete"><font size="+1" face="comic sans ms" colour="blue"><a href="login.do?method=modify" style='text-decoration: none;'>Delete</a></font></display:column>
    </display:table>

</logic:notEmpty>
```

this is my jsp from where i want to get userId value to following servlet

servlet

LoginAction.java

modify method

```
String userId= req.getParameter("userId").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what ur asking, also considering that your JSP is incomplete / unbalanced. That said, all you need to do to submit values captured in a JSP to a servlet is wrap input in a , and post that. E.g.

```
<form method="post" action="LoginAction">
User Id:<input name="userId"/>
<input type="Submit" value="Log in"/>
</form>
```

(assuming the servlet LoginAction.java is published, in DD or annotation, as LoginAction)

Comment: thanks Damo.My problem has been resolved. Thanks for your response.